# Virtual machine host-only network with SSH port forwarding

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, port-forwarding

I've got a Windows XP virtual machine (vmware workstation) which I need protected from the internet. I need it for programming some old hardware, which uses some old software that only runs on Windows XP. My host computer (Windows 7) is connected to the corporate network, so the VM should never be directly connected to the network for security reasons.

I use git for source control of the software, with the remote repository hosted on a cloud platform. So for this I need network access to the VM.

I was thinking about setting the VM in host only mode, then port forwarding SSH from the VM to my host network adapter. Then I could use ssh to sync with the remote repositories using git.

The problem is I'm not a super big network guy. But (a) I don't know if this is safe to do, and (b) I don't know if it even makes sense.

I've never used port forwarding before, I've only ever read about it. Does anyone have any advice. Does this make sense? Is it safe to do this? Is there a better way to do it?

I'm not 100% how it works (obviously). But can I use port forwarding on the host, from the VMware network adapter on port 22 (SSH) to my host network adapter which is connected to the corporate network on port 22. Maybe this doesn't even make sense though, hence the question.

Comment: You've left out too much information. What is your host? What kind of VM? What is doing the port forwarding?

Comment: Ok sorry. I've edited the question. But like I mention in the question, maybe what I'm asking just doesn't make sense. Essentially, I just want to stop all network access to the VM, except for ssh. I guess I could also set up a firewall on the VM and block everything except for ssh.

Comment: What are you going to use to do port forwarding?  What appliance, or driver, or host, or service, or property, or feature?